# Remove Alternative Terminals from settings

Tags: gnome-terminal

I installed hyper terminal and added it to the list of terminals.
I removed the hyper completely but whenever I run

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

It outputs:

```
update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator is dangling; it will be updated with best choice
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /opt/Hyper/hyper
Nothing to configure.
```

the hyper terminal is still in the setting and some warning about the terminal-emulator dangling

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator Edited my post, thanks for informing me about this